# Qlikview | a chart to display: "the top 10% websites get 95% of the traffic"

Tags: qlikview

I have a table with some dimensions, website URL and number of hits.
Sorting it descending by hits, we want to use it to create a graph to display info like the following:
the top 10% of the websites cover 90% of the traffic.

I want this to be by multiple of say 5 (top 5%, top 10%, top 15%, etc...).

What is the best way to do that?
I cannot create the dataset in advance in the script since there are dimensions that I want to be able to filter by in the report, and have the chart updated dynamically accordingly.

Comment: Did either of the blog posts below help you? if so which one? So we can add a correct answer in for future use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm don't know how, but the answer I got here disappeared! So I can't thank the one who provided it..

Anyway, the following link proved to be exactly what I needed: https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2013/12/09/pareto-analysis

And to summarize its content:

1. Create a pivot table and choose your dimension and your basic measure. For example, Product and Sum(Sales).
2. Sort the chart descending by using the measure Sum(Sales) as sort expression. It is not enough just to check “Sort by Y-value”.
3. Add a second expression to calculate the accumulated sales value:
    RangeSum(Above(Sum(Sales), 0, RowNo()))
4. Call this expression Accumulated Sales. The Above() function will return an array of values – all above values in the chart – and the RangeSum() function will sum these numbers.
5. Create a third expression from the previous one; one that calculates the accumulated sales in percent:
    RangeSum(Above(Sum(Sales), 0, RowNo())) / Sum(total Sales). Format it as a percentage and call it Inclusive Percentage.
6. Create a fourth expression from the previous one; one that calculates the accumulated sales in percent, but this time excluding the current row: RangeSum(Above(Sum(Sales), 1, RowNo())) / Sum(total Sales)
   Format it as a percentage and call it Exclusive Percentage.
7. Create a fifth expression for the ABC classification:
     If([Exclusive Percentage] <= 0.8, 'A', If([Exclusive Percentage] <= 0.9, 'B', 'C')). Call this expression Pareto Class. 
   The reason why the Exclusive Percentage is used, is that the classification should be determined by the lower bound of a product’s segment, not the upper.
8. Create a conditional background color, e.g.
     If([Pareto Class] = 'C', LightRed(), If([Pareto Class] = 'B', Yellow()))

Comment: The answer was removed because it was a link-only answer, meaning it just provided a link without discussing the relevant information for solving the question. This answer is also a link-only answer, so it will be deleted for the same reason unless you edit it to state the useful information from the link. This is not an arbitrary rule, but instead one that helps StackOverflow answers be useful even if the links in answers become dead links. You can read more about this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).